# how to use a list item to call and display a string in another fragment

Tags: android, xml

i am a novice in android and i was trying to make an application that has two fragments, one with a listView with topics which when one is clicked it opens a topic description in the other fragment. i would like to know how to also store the large string for the description

Answer (score 0):

If the data is dynamic you can store your topics and desciptions in a sqlite database. You have several possibilities:

1. You load the topic and description at the start and give over the description with a method or an interface to the second fragment.
2. You store the data in a database and give every entry a unique id and use a method or an interface to communicate with the second fragment and put the id to it. And then you use the id to get the description from database.

UPDATE #1

3. You can use arrays in your resource files. Create two arrays. One with your topics and the other with your descriptions. But the topics and descriptions have to be in the same order. For example the description of the second topic have to be on the second position in its array. Now you use the first array for your listview and the second(with the descriptions) in the description fragment. The "setOnItemClickListener" method of the listview have the position as a parameter. This is the same as the position of the topics and desciption in your arrays (when you dont resort anything).

Comment: it is not dynamic i would prefer to use shared prefs and the resource xml files. for example each topic description in its own resource file as a string but i dont know how to assign key value pairs in one fragment then call the description in another. plus how can i know the id listview assigns each list item

Comment: You can use arrays in your resurce files. Create two arrays. One with your topics and the other with your descriptions. But the topics and descriptions have to be in the same order. For example the description of the second topic have to be on the second position in its array. Now you use the first array for your listview and the second(with the descriptions) in the description fragment. The "setOnItemClickListener" method of the listview have the position as a parameter. This is the same as the position of the topics and desciption in your arrays (when you dont resort anything).

Comment: <string-array name="topics">
        <item>HISTORY</item>
        <item>ENTERTAINMENT</item>
        <item>GEOGRAPHY</item>
        <item>POLITICS</item>
        <item>TOURISM</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="description">
        <item>@string/history</item>
        <item>@string/entertainment</item>
        <item>@string/geography</item>
        <item>@string/politics</item>
        <item>@string/tourism</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

Comment: Yes that should work. You can load the array now with getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics) and getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description)